# Java library for byte-array manipulations?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a free library available that contains common methods for manipulating a byte array?

It should be able to perform the following operations at least ob byte arrays but other array types would be nice, too:

- Search for sub-array
- Search and replace
- Insert elements at a certain position
- Delete sub-array at a certain position

I know that all those functions are not high magic but implementing them completely and fool & error proof including the correspondent unit tests takes some time.

Therefore I am searching for a (non-GPL) library that includes those functions.
Does anybody know such a library?

Comment: Often these operations are performed on `String` or `StringBuilder` but these store `char` ratehr than `byte`. Is this binary or text data?

Comment: We are talking about real binary data.

Comment: @Robert, what is the problem with GPL of you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you work with arrays of primitive types, the [Guava library](https://github.com/google/) can help. See more in [*PrimitivesExplained - guava-libraries - Guava's primitives utilities, explained. - Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 1.6+ - Google Project Hosting*](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PrimitivesExplained)

The interesting class is [`com.google.common.primitives.Bytes`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html)

Comment: Interesting library, even if it is a bit large for the simple use case.

Comment: The source is available, so you can easily take just what you want. It's licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

Comment: Do note that the Guava method to search for an array of bytes within another array of bytes is not optimised. I guess it is written under the assumption that you are not working with large arrays of bytes.

Answer (score -1):

I think your first three problems can be solved by **Java.util.Arrays** class, you don't need to for 3rd party library.

```
Arrays.binarySearch() method is for your first problem.
Arrays.fill() method for your second problem.
```

For last problem I can suggest some 3rd party util packages that I know.

Google's Guava, Apache's commons API may help.

Comment: binarySearch() requires a sorted array. And fill only allows you to overwrite each element in a array region with the same value. Therefore both do not output the result I had in mind.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can do what you need by turning your array into a `Collection`. If you don't want to use `Collections`, and you're dealing only with `byte[]`, you could do this something like this:

```
public class A {

    public static byte[] deleteSubarray(byte[] array, byte[] subArray) {
        int p = searchFor(array, subArray);
        if (p == -1)
            return array;
        byte[] result = new byte[array.length - subArray.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
            result[i] = array[i];
        for (int i = p + subArray.length - 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            result[p] = array[i];
            p++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] insertElementAt(byte[] array, byte element, int position) {
        byte[] result = new byte[array.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= position - 1; i++)
            result[i] = array[i];
        result[position] = element;
        for (int i = position + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            result[i] = array[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] searchAndReplace(byte[] array, byte[] search, byte[] replace) {
        if (search.length != replace.length)
            return array;
        int p = searchFor(array, search);
        if (p == -1)
            return array;
        byte[] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < replace.length; i++) {
            result[p] = replace[i];
            p++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int searchFor(byte[] array, byte[] subArray) {
        if (subArray.length > array.length)
            return -1;
        int p = (new String(array)).indexOf(new String(subArray));
        for (int i = 1; i < subArray.length; i++) {
            if (array[p + i] != subArray[i])
                return -1;
        }
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "hello world!";
        String b = "lo w";
        System.out.println(searchFor(a.getBytes(), b.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(new String(searchAndReplace(a.getBytes(), b.getBytes(), "mn x".getBytes())));
        System.out.println(new String(insertElementAt(a.getBytes(), "-".getBytes()[0], 5)));
        System.out.println(new String(deleteSubarray(a.getBytes(), b.getBytes())));
    }

}
```

Output:

> ```
> 3
> helmn xorld!
> hello-world!
> helworld!
> ```

If you're dealing also with other type of arrays, then the `searchFor` doesn't work, but you can easily generalize :)

Comment: Even if we ignore that it is totally inefficient the whole conversions make the code difficult to read because you have one additional line for Array to Collection conversion and two lines for converting the Collection back to an Array. I would prefer for each operation one method.

Comment: I added some simple code showing how to do without `Collections`

Comment: Any reason you are avoid using System.arraycopy(..)? Additionally your version of searchAndReplace does not support differing sizes of search and replace array (that's the most interesting use case of it...).

Comment: I haven't used `System.arraycopy(..)`, but it's a good idea :) I think it's not difficult to extend my version of `searchAndReplace` to support arrays of different size. I haven't done it, because I though it was not neceessary